# How to export EAGLE 9.6.2 design to CADSTAR 2019.0

Tags: eaglecad, cad

Does anyone know how to export board from EAGLE 9.6.2 to CADSTAR 2019.0, so that
CADSTAR can be used for making a layout and further netlist?

Any readily available ULP script might help.
The schematic need not be 100% exported correctly to CADSTAR, only a part of it gets copied correctly will be good enough.

Comment: I hope this help, but it does not work as it is outdated. https://eagle.support.eng.narkive.com/eT8YKh7H/how-to-export-design-to-cadstar

Comment: Its fine even if kicad-> CADSTAR solution is found out. Since EAGLE to kicad transfer is super easy.